# Imprimir valores de un array que puede variar. PHP

Tags: php, html5

Esto haciendo un sistema donde solicito información por inputs y quiero que imprima los tags de HTML para después solo copiar y pegar ese código.

En la primer pantalla se solicita al usuario cierta información para generar por un `for` los tags de `ul` y `li`para imprimirlos en la segunda pantalla.

index.php El usuario puede seleccionar entre 1 o 5 elementos a mostrar
Imagen del Index [image]

```
<?php 

$temas = array(
    '1','2','3','4','5'
);

$propositos = array(
    '1','2','3','4','5'
);

$recursos = array(
    '1','2','3','4','5'
);

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Agenda</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Agenda_W3.php" method="post">
        <p>Selecciona que materia quieres trabajar:
            <select name="materia" id="">
                <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
                <option value="Matemáticas">Matemáticas</option>
                <option value="Física">Física</option>
            </select>
        </p>

        <p>¿Cuantos <strong>"Propositos Especificos"</strong> necesitas para la semana? <select name="no_proposito" id="">
                <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
                <?php foreach ($propositos as $proposito) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $proposito; ?>"><?php echo $proposito; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <hr>
        <p>Sección 1</p>
        <p>¿Cuantos <strong>"Temas"</strong> necesitas? <select name="no_tema1" id="">
                <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
                <?php foreach ($temas as $tema) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $tema; ?>"><?php echo $tema; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </p>

        <p>¿Cuantos <strong>"Recursos"</strong> necesitas? <select name="no_recursos1" id="">
                <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
                <?php foreach ($recursos as $recurso) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $recurso; ?>"><?php echo $recurso; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </p>        
        <hr>
        <p>Sección 2</p>
        <p>¿Cuantos <strong>"Temas"</strong> necesitas? <select name="no_tema2" id="">
                <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
                <?php foreach ($temas as $tema) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $tema; ?>"><?php echo $tema; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </p>

        <p>¿Cuantos <strong>"Recursos"</strong> necesitas? <select name="no_recursos2" id="">
                <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
                <?php foreach ($recursos as $recurso) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $recurso; ?>"><?php echo $recurso; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </p>        

        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Esta es la salida de mi Array en el index.php

```
Array
(
    [materia] => Física
    [no_proposito] => 5
    [no_tema1] => 2
    [no_recursos1] => 4
    [no_tema2] => 3
    [no_recursos2] => 1
)
```

Segunda pantalla uso esa información para generar las viñetas de acuerdo a lo que el usuario seleccionó en el index.php e envió a un segundo formulario.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    $bloques = array(
        'I','II','III','IV','V','VI','VII','VIII','IX','X','XI','XII','XIII'
    );
    /*Almacena el digito en una variable para usarse en un ciclo*/
    $no_proposito = $_POST['no_proposito'];
    $no_tema1 = $_POST['no_tema1'];
    $no_recurso1 = $_POST['no_recursos1'];
    $no_tema2 = $_POST['no_tema2'];
    $no_recurso2 = $_POST['no_recursos2'];
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Agenda W3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="w3-container agenda">
        <p>Agenda para la materia: <?php printf($materia);?> </p>
        <form action="genera_html.php" method="post" target="_blank">
            <div class="w3-row w3-round bloque">
                <div class="w3-col w3-container ">
                    <p>BLOQUE: 
                        <select name="no_bloque" id=""><!-- El usuario selecciona el bloque -->
                            <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
                            <?php foreach ($bloques as $romano) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php printf($romano); ?>"> <?php printf($romano); ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>:<input type="text" name="nombre_bloque" placeholder="Nombre del bloque">
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="w3-row  objetivo">
                <div class="w3-col w3-padding-small w3-container m4 l3 objetivo_tit">
                    <p class="amarillo"><strong>Objetivo</strong></p>
                </div>
                <div class="w3-col w3-container m8 l9 objetivo_content">
                    <p><input type="text" name="titulo_objetivo" placeholder="Objetivo"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>    
            <div class="w3-row  propositos">
                <div class="w3-col w3-padding-small w3-container m4 l3 propositos_tit">
                    <p class="amarillo"><strong>Propósitos específicos</strong></p>
                </div>
                <div class="w3-col w3-container m8 l9 propositos_content">
                    <?php
                        $html="<ul>"; /*Definimos etiqueta <ul> que se usará para concatenación*/
                        for ($i=1; $i <= $no_proposito; $i++) { /*Se itera sobre la variable para imprimir n cantidad de <li>*/
                            $html.="<li><input type=\"text\" name=\"proposito$i\" placeholder=\"Descripción del proposito\"></li>";
                        }
                        $html.="</ul>"; /*Definimos etiqueta <ul> que se usará para concatenación*/
                        echo $html; /*Imprime la lista contatenada*/
                     ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="w3-row w3-round w3-padding-small tema">
                <div class="w3-col w3-container ">
                    <p><strong>TEMA <select name="numero_tema1" id="">
                        <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                    </select>:
                    <?php 
                        $html="<ul>"; /*Definimos etiqueta <ul> que se usará para concatenación*/
                        for ($i=1; $i <= $no_tema1; $i++) { /*Se itera sobre la variable para imprimir n cantidad de <li>*/
                            $html.="<li><input type=\"text\" name=\"no_tema$i\" placeholder=\"Descripción del proposito\"></li>";
                        }
                        $html.="</ul>"; /*Definimos etiqueta <ul> que se usará para concatenación*/
                        echo $html; /*Imprime la lista contatenada*/
                     ?>
                    </strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="w3-row  actividades">
                <div class="w3-col m6 l8 act_column">
                    <div class="w3-row  w3-padding-small act_tit">
                        <p class="amarillo"><strong>Actividades</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-row  act_cont">
                        <p><input type="text" name="descripcion1_actividad" placeholder="Descripción de actividad"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="w3-col m6 l4 rec_column">
                    <div class="w3-row  w3-padding-small rec_tit">
                        <p class="amarillo"><strong>Recursos</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-row  rec_cont">
                        <p>
                            <input type="text" name="descripcion1_recursos" placeholder="Descripción del recurso">
                        </p>
                        <?php /*Genera lista de los recursos para cada materia*/
                            $html="<ul>"; /*Definimos etiqueta <ul> que se usará para concatenación*/
                            for ($i=1; $i <= $no_recurso1; $i++) { /*Se itera sobre la variable para imprimir n cantidad de <li>*/
                                $html.="<li><input type=\"text\" name=\"no_recurso$i\" placeholder=\"Descripción del proposito\"></li>";
                            }
                            $html.="</ul>"; /*Definimos etiqueta <ul> que se usará para concatenación*/
                            echo $html; /*Imprime la lista contatenada*/
                         ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="w3-row w3-round w3-padding-small tema">
                <div class="w3-col w3-container ">
                    <p>
                        <strong>TEMA <select name="numero_tema2" id="">
                            <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                        </select>:
                        <?php 
                            $html="<ul>"; /*Definimos etiqueta <ul> que se usará para concatenación*/
                            for ($i=1; $i <= $no_tema2; $i++) { /*Se itera sobre la variable para imprimir n cantidad de <li>*/
                                $html.="<li><input type=\"text\" name=\"no_tema$i\" placeholder=\"Descripción del proposito\"></li>";
                            }
                            $html.="</ul>"; /*Definimos etiqueta <ul> que se usará para concatenación*/
                            echo $html; /*Imprime la lista contatenada*/
                         ?>
                        </strong>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="w3-row  actividades">
                <div class="w3-col m6 l8 act_column w3-padding">
                    <div class="w3-row  w3-padding-small act_tit">
                        <p class="amarillo"><strong>Actividades</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-row  act_cont w3-padding">
                        <p><input type="text" name="descripcion2_actividad" placeholder="Descripción de actividad"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="w3-col m6 l4 rec_column w3-padding">
                    <div class="w3-row  w3-padding-small rec_tit">
                        <p class="amarillo"><strong>Recursos</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-row  rec_cont w3-padding">
                        <p><input type="text" name="descripcion2_recursos" placeholder="Descripción del recurso"></p>

                        <?php 
                            $html="<ul>"; /*Definimos etiqueta <ul> que se usará para concatenación*/
                            for ($i=1; $i <= $no_recurso2; $i++) { /*Se itera sobre la variable para imprimir n cantidad de <li>*/
                                $html.="<li><input type=\"text\" name=\"no_recursos$i\" placeholder=\"Descripción del proposito\"></li>";
                            }
                            $html.="</ul>"; /*Definimos etiqueta <ul> que se usará para concatenación*/
                            echo $html; /*Imprime la lista contatenada*/
                         ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Validar datos" >
        </form> 
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Este es array de mi segundo código.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Las variables *Undefined*, debo de usar isset para que no me envíe ese error?

Lo que no sé es como imprimir los elementos de array ya que puede variar de acuerdo a la información de la primera pantalla. Por ejemplo en la imagen anterior no se están usando las variables *no_tema4*, *no_tema5*,etc.

Este es mi tercer código para imprimir la información del array y para que después sea impresa solo el HTML con la etiqueta `<pre>`

```
<?php

$no_bloque = $_POST['no_bloque'];
$nombre_bloque = $_POST['nombre_bloque'];
$titulo_objetivo = $_POST['titulo_objetivo'];
$proposito1 = $_POST['proposito1'];
$proposito2 = $_POST['proposito2'];
$proposito3 = $_POST['proposito3'];
$proposito4 = $_POST['proposito4'];
$proposito5 = $_POST['proposito5'];
$numero_tema1 = $_POST['numero_tema1'];
$no_tema1 = $_POST['no_tema1'];
$no_tema2 = $_POST['no_tema2'];
$no_tema3 = $_POST['no_tema3'];
$no_tema4 = $_POST['no_tema4'];
$no_tema5 = $_POST['no_tema5'];
$descripcion1_actividad = $_POST['descripcion1_actividad'];
$descripcion1_recursos = $_POST['descripcion1_recursos'];
$no_recurso1 = $_POST['no_recurso1'];
$no_recurso2 = $_POST['no_recurso2'];
$no_recurso3 = $_POST['no_recurso3'];
$no_recurso4 = $_POST['no_recurso4'];
$no_recurso5 = $_POST['no_recurso5'];
$numero_tema2 = $_POST['numero_tema2'];
$descripcion2_actividad = $_POST['descripcion2_actividad'];
$descripcion2_recursos = $_POST['descripcion2_recursos'];
$no_recursos1 = $_POST['no_recursos1'];
$no_recursos2 = $_POST['no_recursos2'];
$no_recursos3 = $_POST['no_recursos3'];
$no_recursos4 = $_POST['no_recursos4'];
$no_recursos5 = $_POST['no_recursos5'];

/*$no_proposito = $_POST['no_proposito'];*/

if ($_POST) {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($_POST, true));
    echo count($_POST). " elementos";
    echo '</pre>';
    }
echo '<hr>';
?>
<div class="w3-container agenda">
        <div class="w3-row w3-round bloque">
            <div class="w3-col w3-container ">
                <p>BLOQUE <?php printf($no_bloque); ?>:  <?php printf($nombre_bloque); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="w3-row  objetivo">
            <div class="w3-col w3-padding-small w3-container m4 l3 objetivo_tit">
                <p class="amarillo"><strong>Objetivo.</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-col w3-container m8 l9 objetivo_content">  
                <p><?php printf($titulo_objetivo); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="w3-row  propositos">
            <div class="w3-col w3-padding-small w3-container m4 l3 propositos_tit">
                <p class="amarillo"><strong>Propósitos específicos</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-col w3-container m8 l9 propositos_content">  
                <ul>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="w3-row w3-round w3-padding-small tema">
            <div class="w3-col w3-container ">
                <p><strong>TEMA I: Las mátemáticas en la historia</strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="w3-row  actividades">
            <div class="w3-col m6 l8 act_column">
                <div class="w3-row  w3-padding-small act_tit">
                    <p class="amarillo"><strong>Actividades</strong></p>
                </div>
                <div class="w3-row  act_cont">
                    <p>Actividades Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit sequi possimus quia impedit qui quibusdam asperiores culpa, optio excepturi quo nostrum ad ipsa nihil ullam dignissimos, ab obcaecati odit voluptatum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="w3-col m6 l4 rec_column">
            <div class="w3-row  w3-padding-small rec_tit">
                <p class="amarillo"><strong>Recursos</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-row  rec_cont">
                <p>Recursos Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit sequi possimus quia impedit qui quibusdam asperiores culpa, optio excepturi quo nostrum ad ipsa nihil ullam dignissimos, ab obcaecati odit voluptatum.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Objetivo de de esta agenda semanal</li>
                    <li>Este es otro objetivo semanal</li>
                    <li>Este es el tercer objetivo semanal</li>
                    <li>Este es el tercer objetivo semanal</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="w3-row w3-round w3-padding-small tema">
            <div class="w3-col w3-container ">
                <p><strong>TEMA II: Las mátemáticas en la historia</strong></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="w3-row  actividades">
            <div class="w3-col m6 l8 act_column w3-padding">
                <div class="w3-row  w3-padding-small act_tit">
                    <p class="amarillo"><strong>Actividades</strong></p>
                </div>
                <div class="w3-row  act_cont w3-padding">
                    <p>Actividades Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit sequi possimus quia impedit qui quibusdam asperiores culpa, optio excepturi quo nostrum ad ipsa nihil ullam dignissimos, ab obcaecati odit voluptatum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-col m6 l4 rec_column w3-padding">
                <div class="w3-row  w3-padding-small rec_tit">
                    <p class="amarillo"><strong>Recursos</strong></p>
                </div>
                <div class="w3-row  rec_cont w3-padding">
                    <p>Recursos Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit sequi possimus quia impedit qui quibusdam asperiores culpa, optio excepturi quo nostrum ad ipsa nihil ullam dignissimos, ab obcaecati odit voluptatum.</p>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Objetivo de de esta agenda semanal</li>
                            <li>Este es otro objetivo semanal</li>
                            <li>Este es el tercer objetivo semanal</li>
                            <li>Este es el tercer objetivo semanal</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

PD: Aun me hace falta imprimir los tags de HTML.
PD: Soy nuevo programando en PHP.

Comment: pon ejemplos para que quede más claro

Comment: Quisiera imprimir la información de la segunda pantalla usando las etiquetas HTML, investigando un poquito veo que debo de usar la etiqueta `<pre>` pero no se como atraer los valores del array ya que pueden variar.

Comment: La pregunta se entiende, pero si pusieras un ejemplo de como queda el array actualmente y otro ejemplo de como quisieras que quedara se podría observar de mejor manera

Comment: Ah ok, dame un segundo para editar mi información.

Comment: Listo @Sr1871, espero no confundirte.

Comment: Entonces lo único que quieres hacer es en tu tercera pantalla imprimir por ejemplo `<li>no_propsito3 = Proposito 3</li>`? o como las quisieras imprimir?

Comment: Si, para que se impriman los tags de `<li>` con la variable y además que todo el código HTML, se imprima usando la etiqueta `<pre>` para poder copiarlo y pegarlo en otro lado. Tengo problemas para poder mandar a traer esas etiquetas `<li>` de manera dinámica.

Comment: No entendí la pregunta, pero creo que tanto la explicación como una posible solución se hacen difíciles hasta de explicar porque a mi juicio el fondo del problema es que se puede resolver de una forma más simple. Por poner un ejemplo: si en vez de estos tres arrays: `$temas = array(
    '1','2','3','4','5'
);` `$propositos = array(
    '1','2','3','4','5'
);` y `$recursos = array(
    '1','2','3','4','5'
);` tú crearas **una verdadera estructura de datos** representada en un sólo elemento, luego podrías mostrar lo que quisieras según lo que haya sido seleccionado... No sé si me entiendes

Comment: Podría proponerte una solución basada en una **verdadera estructura de datos** si te interesa, pero para hacer eso se necesita entender el problema, lo que quieres lograr, el contexto. ¿Te interesaría esta solución? ¿Podrías explicarlo brevemente, claramente, sin demasiadas complicaciones?

Comment: @A.Cedano Mi problema que los usuarios editan una página donde hay herramientas de formato, la mayoría copia y pega de word y modifican las tablas sin querer a veces hasta texto enriquecido pegan. 
Se me ocurrió un sistema donde por medio de un formulario les solicitara la cantidad de viñetas que necesita (En esa sección de código me ayudaste), después se genera otro formulario donde deben de llenar esas viñetas y finalmente debe de entregar una plantilla HTML ,que ya tengo, la información que los usuarios llenaron.

Answer (score 1):

simplemente haz un foreach a $_POST en lugar de imprimir todo con un post

```
if (!empty($_POST)):?>
  <pre>
     <?php foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
         echo '<li>'.$key.' es '.$value.'</li>';
     }?>
  </pre>
  <hr>
<?php endif?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no me funciona porque me va imprimir todo el array en etiquetas li. Creo que tendré que almacenar los valores en diferentes arrays para aplicar tu sugerencia. Intentaré guardar en arrays diferentes

Comment: por favor revisa [answer] y no ocupes la zona de respuestas para colocar comentarios o aclaraciones